# Nothing appears in my demo

Tags: ios, swift

What does this error mean and how can i fix it ? I have actually chosen an empty tampelet to do my app from the scratch my self but some one told me that there is such method in deligate that is supposed to be deleted but it seems that it more than just that ;)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method with this method:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

Which will remove your error and I can see a break point at line 17 in your screen shot which is looks like:

[image]

so remove it and run your project again.

Comment: clean your project with command + shift + k. and build it again.

Comment: This is what i get now :)     "2015-09-14 16:20:28.299 ToDoList[97006:18813279] Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Storyboard' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?"

Comment: Just click on main.storyboard then click on your first view controller and then go to attribute inspector then in second section mark at `Is Initial ViewController`